# is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server docker compose

Tags: javascript, node.js, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I want to create connection in my nodejs to mariadb. my nodejs and mariadb build in docker compose, for nodejs can access public with dns but for mariadb can not, it is can access via server with ip. I always get error **Host '172.19.0.2' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server  docker**

can anyone help me how to connect to mariadb. Or what is possible docker container connect to localhost mariadb in server?

Note: edited

this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  mariadb:
    driver: local

networks:
    db:
        driver: bridge

services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.6
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_USER: admin1
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin1
    expose:
        - "40000"
    ports:
        - "40000:3306"
    volumes:
     - mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      db:
              
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "40001"
    ports:
      - "40001:80"
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=mariadb
      - PMA_PORT=3306 
    networks:
      db:
```

Comment: In your docker-compose file have you exposed the correct ports? the default port for mariadb is `3306` so if not then try again by exposing this port. [mongodb-example](https://github.com/kartik1225/docker_node_sample/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)

Comment: my ports is correct @KartikGarasia

Comment: Can you share your `docker-compose` snippet for `mariadb`?

Comment: Okay, I already edit my post @KartikGarasia

Comment: As I can see you have forwarded port `40000` so maybe you can try accessing with `192.168.0.1: 40000`

Comment: I can access with ip:40001 to phpmyadmin, but in nodejs can not @KartikGarasia